# Unmarshal body response from task queue

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm using go and google task queue in order to create  some a sync jobs.

I'm passing the data to the worker method successfully but i can't unmarshal the data in order to use it.

I tried different ways i'm getting an unmarshal error

```
 err um &json.SyntaxError{msg:"invalid character 'i' in literal false (expecting 'a')", Offset:2}
```

This is how i'm sending the data to the queue

```
    keys := make(map[string][]string)
    keys["filenames"] = req.FileNames // []string

    t := taskqueue.NewPOSTTask("/deletetask", keys)
    _, err = taskqueue.Add(ctx, t, "delete")
```

And this is how i tried to unmarshal it

```
 type Files struct {
fileNames string `json:"filenames"`
 }


func worker(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
c := appengine.NewContext(r)

var objmap map[string]json.RawMessage
b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
if err != nil {
    c.Debugf("err io  %#v", err)
}
c.Debugf("b  %#v", string(b[:])) //Print: b  "filenames=1.txt&filenames=2.txt"

err = json.Unmarshal(b, &objmap)
if err != nil {
    c.Debugf("err um %#v", err)
}
 //this didn't work as well  same err
    f := []Files{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(b, &f)
 }
```

Comment: The parameters passed to the task aren't json, so unmarshalling as such won't work. Your code can be almost identical to the example here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/taskqueue/overview-push

Answer (score 0):

Arguments to tasks are sent as POST-values, you assign a slice of strings as the POST-value for the key `filenames`.

Then you try to deserialize the full POST request body as JSON.

A simple solution would be to split up each file in one task and just send the file name as a string value, then it would be something like:

```
// Add tasks
for i := range req.FileNames {
    postValues := url.Values{}
    postValues.Set("fileName", req.FileNames[i])

    t := taskqueue.NewPOSTTask("/deletetask", postValues)
    if _, err := taskqueue.Add(ctx, t, "delete"); err != nil {
        c.Errorf("Failed add task, error: %v, fileName: %v", err, req.FileNames[i])
    }
}

// The actual delete worker
func worker(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
    fileName := r.FormValue("fileName")

    ctx.Infof("Deleting: %v", fileName)
}
```